Could not find `pda` and `state` in `mpl_token_metadata`
I have been trying to execute an anchor build command in my program, but I am facing some errors for the mpl_token_metadata package.
The error is pointed out for the below block of code:
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    pda::{find_master_edition_account, find_metadata_account},
    state::DataV2,
};

The mpl_token_metadata version I am using is:
mpl-token-metadata = "4.1.2" 

The other dependencies in my cargo.toml file is:
anchor-lang = { version = "0.30.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
anchor-spl = { version = "0.30.0", features = ["metadata"] }

The error I am getting is:

Can someone help me understand and solve this error?

These imports are for older versions
From the latest version import them like this
use mpl_token_metadata::accounts::{ MasterEdition, Metadata as MetadataAccount };

usage
    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MetadataAccount::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub metadata_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        address = MasterEdition::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub master_edition_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

docs.rs reference

Thanks ser, the solution worked. I updated my imports, and made necessary changes in code.
